# Typeahead without bloodhound returns multiple errors

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

In my `custom.js` I have the following code that works:

```
var cities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/api/search/city?city=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('.typeahead').typeahead(
{
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'cities',
    display: 'title',
    source: cities
});
```

But I'd like to remove bloodhound and still use the remote feature. The reason is that `minLength` doesn't work when using bloodhound, plus the I don't need an additional suggestion engine on top of what the remote query returns. I've found [this snippet](https://www.ur-ban.com/2015/08/04/using-typeahead-js-without-bloodhound/) that I've applied:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    highlight: true,
},
{
  name: 'cities',
  display: 'title',
  source: function(query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
    $.get('/api/search/city?city=' + query, function(data) {
      asyncResults(data);
    });
  }
})
```

But as soon as I get to character 3 and above (as defined in `minLength`), the console shows:

```
app.js:3166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"ti
    at isArrayLike (app.js:3166)
    at Function.each (app.js:3028)
    at Object.each (typeahead.bundle.js:966)
    at Dataset.getSuggestionsFragment [as _getSuggestionsFragment] (typeahead.bundle.js:1662)
    at Dataset.renderSuggestions [as _renderSuggestions] (typeahead.bundle.js:1628)
    at Dataset.append [as _append] (typeahead.bundle.js:1620)
    at async (typeahead.bundle.js:1724)
    at Object.success (custom.js:200)
    at fire (app.js:5945)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (app.js:6075)
```

I've found it difficult to debug as I'm not sure about all the errors that are showing. Is it that `isArrayLike` is the culprit that then results in all the subsequent errors?

**Update**

If I use `console.log(data)` it shows, as expected:

```
[
   {
      "title":"City1"
   },
   {
      "title":"City2"
   },
   {
      "title":"City3"
   },
   {
      "title":"City4"
   },
   {
      "title":"City5"
   }
]
```

This is as expected.

Comment: Dump out `data` in the `$.get` callback. It seems it's not an array or something else messes up the response.

Comment: I've just updated the answer with the data dump.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out `data` was a string. What solved the problem was replacing `data` with `JSON.parse(data)`.